# loading colors from properties file

Tags: java

how would I load a color from a properties file

for example my properties file shows

```
color=0xfffff
```

& lets say for example I want to use `0xfffff` to set the color of my text

i have tried a few thing but I either get wrong color showing, error before launching &/or `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Post what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
String sNumber = "0xfffff";
sNumber = sNumber.substring(2); // removing the prefix 0x
int number = Integer.parseInt(sNumber, 16);
```

Comment: success :) thanks that appears to be working for me & with loading the properties file

Comment: @user2819096 Accept this answer, instead of changing the title of the question :)

Comment: oh didnt know about that, a quick google showed me how to do that ;) ive accepted your answer now :)